# Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3+\sqrt[3]{3}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Given a real number $\alpha:=\sqrt{3+\sqrt[3]{3}}$, I've got to determine the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. I know that squaring results in: $\alpha^2=3+\sqrt[3]{3}$. Now I don't know how to go on because of $\sqrt[3]{3}$, that is obviously not included in $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there any general strategy to find a minimal polynomial?

Comment: You would like to do $(\alpha^2-3)^3=3$ then move all terms into one side. then you will get the minimal polynomial

Comment: You are making progress.  Subtract 3 from both sides of your equation, and cube the resulting sides.  Now you have a polynomial equation for $\alpha$ and the remaining task is to determine its irreducible factors over the field of rational numbers.

Comment: To prove that the polynomial is irreducible you can apply [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion) with the prime $p=3$. Observe how the constant term $-3^3+3$ is a multiple of $3$ but not of $3^2$, and all other coefficients are multiples of $3$, except for the leading coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just continue with the algebraic manipulation to find $$(x^2 - 3)^3 - 3 = x^6 - 9 x^4 + 27 x^2 - 30$$

and this is the minimal polynomial as it is irreducible by Eisenstein with $p=3$: $p | 9,27,30$ and $p^3 \not | 30$.